# The speed of executing simple commands on Redis is slow

Tags: redis

I have found in Redis's `slowlog` that some simple commands take a long time to execute, such as `set KEY:TEST String` where the size of the string is around 1.5KB. The execution time recorded in the `slowlog` is over 400 milliseconds. I am wondering what could be the possible reasons for this, as this is not a usual occurrence and the same command executes normally under different circumstances.

My redis is totally 32GB and now 4GB is used.

How is the execution time of Redis `slowlog` calculated? If there is an interruption (such as thread switching or blocking) during the execution of a command, will the time of interruption also be recorded in the execution time of `slowlog`?